# VBA code for algebraic calculation depending on the criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I want macro for:
I have 5 columns where I want  like

```
COL 1    COL 2      COL 3    COL 4   COL5
 JAN      13         0         1
 JAN      12         8         7
 FEB      13         7         4
 FEB      14         7         5
 MAR      44         10         7
```

now i want to calculate on col 5 = (sum of col2 values ) / (sum of col 3  values- sum of values col 4)  which belongs to JAN and i want this solution to print on 1 cell of COL5

similarly for other months output should print on  first cell belongs to FEB cell in col 1

Please i am very poor in this macro coding part . can someone help me to decode this one.

For better understanding of my problem i attaching image also
[image]

Comment: [`SUMIF` function - Office support](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b)

Comment: That's a terrible image

Comment: Jan will be an error as the formula = `25/0` what do you want to do there?

Answer (score 0):

Put this in E2 and copy/drag down.

```
=IF(A2<>A1,IFERROR(SUMIF(A:A,A2,B:B)/(SUMIF(A:A,A2,C:C)-SUMIF(A:A,A2,D:D)),0),"")
```

You will want to change the `,0` to what every you want in place of when it tries to divide by 0.

Jan resolves to `25/0` which is an error I put `0` in for the error.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the formula it is very helpful .But I also want macro code for these.

Comment: Can u help me with that??

Comment: This is not the original sheet ,this is only for sample. I won't get zero for the original data.

Comment: Ok no problem , In code I am getting problem in how to print the output in 1 cell of every month .if you help me in these it will be helpful. Otherwise no problem as you wish .

Comment: You need to post the code you have tried in your original post using [edit] and point to the specific part that is not correct.